# How to set Spring active profile while running in WebLogic

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic

How can I specify spring active profile while running spring boot application (as a war) in WebLogic? How to pass different -Dspring.profiles.active JVM arguments for different application deployed?

All suggestions welcome!

Thanks,

Comment: Depends how you start your application.

Comment: It looks that I am not so familiar with WebLogic, the only option that I am aware of is that you deploy the app (either ear or war) and then it automatically starts it but you have an option to stop or start it.  How can I pass the argument in that case?

Comment: did you find any better solution to pass the profile from outside the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different ways to specify a profile in spring boot.
In your case, the better way is to add the property `spring.profiles.active` inside the `application.properties`, to avoid pasing it as argument when you launch the apps.

I hope my response help you.

Good luck